# Search box with various filters

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table name `voice` with tele_no, date_time and appointment as records. I am trying filter with various combination. If i use `OR` then it include all fields, If i use `AND` then all fields must be entered. How to use combination, mean if i type single field or combination of multiple fields. It should return query

```
$result =mysqli_query($hello,"
SELECT voice.*
     , record.* 
  FROM voice (voice.tele_no = '$tele' AND voice.tele_no<>'')
    OR (voice.date_time between '$date_fm' and '$date_to' AND voice.date_time<>'')
    OR (voice.appointment= '$tele' AND voice.appointment<>'')
```

Comment: You seem to be missing a WHERE keyword. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

I would use a flexible prepared statement here, something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM voice
WHERE
    (tele_no = ? OR tele_no IS NULL) AND
    (date_time BETWEEN ? AND ? OR date_time IS NULL) AND
    (appointment = ? OR appointment IS NULL);
```

Should any of the three columns appearing in the `WHERE` clause be `NULL`, then that particular condition would effectively no-op and logically drop out of the query.  Note that to implement this from PHP, you would need to use one of several PHP's prepared statement libraries.

Comment: "prepared statement libraries" ? You mean db-driver?

Comment: No, I mean any of several libraries in PHP which support prepared statements.  But, this is not the main focus of the question from what I can tell.

Comment: No it's no the main focus. I get that. But I have never heard the term before. As I see it it just db-drivers that can support prepared statements and there are no such thing as "PHP prepared statement libraries" but please tell if I got it all wrong. I'm just curios :-)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld There are multiple PHP libraries offering prepared statements. Most popular is PDO.

Comment: @Dharman - thanks for claryifing. This is then just simply a matter of how you put the words! (For me: 1. "Prepared statement libraries" and 2. "Libraries that offers prepared statements" are two different things where 1=> libraries with it's main focus on prepared statements while 2=> prepared statements are included in a library)